# Create a new user for MongoDB inside Docker

Tags: docker, mongodb

I'm using the default MongoDB Docker image and I'm trying to create a new user for the database.

I'm currently trying to do it this way:

```
FROM docker.io/mongo:3.2

MAINTAINER <alexandernst> alexandernst@gmail.com

ADD create_ddbb.js /tmp/

RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log \
    && sleep 5 && mongo foobar /tmp/create_ddbb.js
```

And the `create_ddbb.js`:

```
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "*******",
      pwd: "*******************",
      roles: [
         { role: "readWrite", db: "foobar" }
      ]
    }
);
```

And when I build the Dockerfile, I see:

```
Step 4 : RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log       && sleep 5 && mongo foobar /tmp/create_ddbb.js
 ---> Running in 58ba44d02508
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 9
child process started successfully, parent exiting
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6
connecting to: foobar
Successfully added user: {
        "user" : "***********",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "foobar"
                }
        ]
}
 ---> e73b6c8c8b83
Removing intermediate container 58ba44d02508
Successfully built e73b6c8c8b83
```

so the user is created, but then when I try to connect, I get:

```
mongo_1  | 2016-05-13T17:44:02.159+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 172.20.0.4:41294 #1 (1 connection now open)
mongo_1  | 2016-05-13T17:44:02.160+0000 I ACCESS   [conn1] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for ********* on foobar from client 172.20.0.4 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user *********@foobar
mongo_1  | 2016-05-13T17:44:02.160+0000 I NETWORK  [conn1] end connection 172.20.0.4:41294 (0 connections now open)
```

Why is that happening? How can I persist the created user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution:

Inside your `Dockerfile`:

```
ADD create_ddbb.js /tmp/

RUN mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log \
    && sleep 5 \
    && mongo <YOUR DATABASE> /tmp/create_ddbb.js
```

Inside the `create_ddbb.js`:

```
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "your_user",
      pwd: "********************",
      roles: [
         { role: "dbOwner", db: "your_database" }
      ]
    }
,
    {
        w: "majority",
        wtimeout: 5000
    }
);
db.createCollection("test");
```

The `createColleciton("test")` at the end is extremely important. Without that, the `createUser` isn't applied. I don't know why exactly, sorry.

Comment: We have redacted the first edit. You should change your password anyway.

Comment: What's in the `mongo.conf` file?

Comment: @Ascalonian This is the default `mongo.conf`file that you get from Docker 
`FROM docker.io/mongo:3.2`

Comment: @alexandernst - Thanks! I am just using `mongo:latest` so I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

the user should be added in the admin database so like this:

`RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log \
    && sleep 5 && mongo foobar /tmp/create_ddbb.js`

Comment: Do you mean `mongo admin /tmp/create_ddbb.js`? If so, I tried that and it's still not working (same output).

Answer (score 0):

I could not make the @alexandernst's solution run. In combination with https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/329 I just had to create my Dockerfile so and it wored.

```
FROM docker.io/mongo:latest
COPY create_ddbb.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

The create_ddbb.js was similar to @alexandernst's, but without the last line which created a test collection.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use the Dockerfile. Instead I used docker-compose.yml to specify the container.
Below is the content of docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: container-mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: root-db

    volumes:
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
```

Create a directory `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` and create `mongo-init.js` file. and put the below code to add user.

```
print("Started adding the users.");
db = db.getSiblingDB("admin");
db.createUser({
  user: "userx",
  pwd: "1234",
  roles: [{ role: "readWrite", db: "admin" }],
});
print("End adding the user roles.");
```

Then run docker compose up from the directory where you have kept the docker compose.yml.
The file tree should look like:

```
project-directory
 ┣ docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
 ┃ ┗ mongo-init.js
 ┗ docker-compose.yaml
```

Check for the logs if you encounter any errors.

Answer (score 0):

An example of Pranu Pranav's solution is here:

https://github.com/LukeMwila/multi-container-nginx-react-node-mongo/blob/master/docker-compose.yml